# unable to start service intent; a IntentService inside an activity

Tags: android, android-service

I have such a Service inside an Activity as:

```
public class StudyHalls extends ExpandableListActivity 
implements OnChildClickListener {

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        ...
}

public class RefreshService extends IntentService {

    public RefreshService() {
        super("RefreshService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...
    }

}
}
```

The Service will be started in another activity through:

```
   startService(new Intent(this, StudyHalls.RefreshService.class));
```

Lastly, I add the Service into manifest:

```
     <service
        android:name="com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls.RefreshService" />
```

Here's the error info:

```
    12-26 10:11:14.093: W/ActivityManager(70): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study/.StudyHalls$RefreshService }: not found
```

EDIT: thx to Thompson, I've made a change to manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name="com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService" />
```

but I still can't start service with the error:

```
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1929) 
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    12-26 10:44:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an inner class.  You need to change the manifest to this:

```
<service
    android:name="com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService" />
```

Comment: thx, but I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.StudyHalls$RefreshService`